# c# Universal Windows console App, Camera error "This object must be initialised... "

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

When I start debugging a Universal Windows console application and initialise the camera I get the following error.

When excute this line: (I execute it in Program.Main )

`await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(captureInitSettings);`

See error:
"This object must be initialised in order to perform the requested operation."

When I use a normal Universal Windows application it works correctly but in console show error..

Here I have 2 questions.

Why do I get an error in the console app?

and

In case of not being able to use a console application, could I use a normal Universal Windows application by passing parameters to it or will it give me an error in a linux because it does not have a graphical interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I get an error in the console app?

This behavior is expected, the `InitializeAsync` should be called from the main UI thread of your app. So you can't call it from a console application.

> could I use a normal Universal Windows application by passing parameters to it or will it give me an error in a linux because it does not have a graphical interface?

No, you can't run a normal UWP in linux without a graphical interface.